# how to set up hive database connection inside spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

New to spark and hive. Currently I can run spark 1.5.2 and I also have access to hive from the command line. I want to be able to programmatically connect to the hive database, run a query and extract the data to a dataframe, all inside spark. I imagine this sort of workflow is pretty standard. But I have no idea how to do it.

Right now I know I can get a HiveContext in spark:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;
```

I can do all my querying inside hive like

```
SHOW TABLES; 
>>customers
  students
  ...
```

Then  I can get data from the tables:

```
SELECT * FROM customers limit 100;
```

How do I string these 2 together inside spark?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the `hive-site.xml` for Spark? Are you aware there is a thing called SparkSQL?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have not. After I saw your comment, I searched on my cluster and found that there is a hive-site.xml in a few places, such as: /etc/conf/hive-site.xml, /etc/hive/conf.cloudera.hive/hive-site.xml. I guess I need to copy these to my home directory and somehow use them?

Comment: I believe `/etc/conf/hive-site.xml` is a symlink to the other one. You'll need to link/copy that into `$SPARK_HOME/conf`

Comment: @cricket_007 I have no sudo permission on the cluster and was not able to link or copy the file to the spark path on the cluster. Is there a way to do this without sudo privilege?

Comment: Last time I was on a cloudera cluster I did `spark-submit --driver-class-path /etc/spark/conf:/etc/hive/conf`. Obviously, that's only good for running a Spark application, though

Answer (score 0):

// sc is an existing SparkContext.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

// Queries are expressed in HiveQL

```
val tablelist = sqlContext.sql("show tables")
val custdf = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM customers limit 100") 

tablelist.collect().foreach(println)     
custdf.collect().foreach(println)
```

Comment: For more details please refer the Spark documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html

Comment: More specifically, the Hive section. https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

Comment: @ArvindKumar I tried your code and tablelist came out containing nothing in it. I suspect that the hive context has to be connected to hive database on the same system somehow.

Comment: Try giving the database name sqlContext.sql("use databasename"). You can also check the same in interactive spark-shell.